# Сохранение базы данных sqlite3 после выключения бота Heroku

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot, heroku

есть ли возможность сохранить данные базе данных после выключения Telegram бота на Heroku?

Как я понял heroku после выключения откатывает все изменения до момента деплоя, есть ли вариант сохранить данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, невозможно. На Heroku файловая система временная. Платформа может в любой момент убить ваш инстанс, запустить несколько его копий или перекинуть его на другой сервак. Используйте полноценную СУБД.